# Cannot write to `-' (Broken pipe) when trying to install a repository signature key

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I’m trying to install [INetSim](http://www.inetsim.org) on Ubunutu 14.04 desktop. I edited the sources list with the pre compiled Debian Packages. Then when trying to install the signature key using `wget` I run across this issue here when I run the command:

```
sudo wget -O - 'http://www.inetsim.org/inetsim.org-archive-signing-key.asc' | apt-key add -
```

I get a broken pipe issue above.

What would be the reason for this? Do I have to add something after:

```
apt-key add
```

[image]

Comment: Try "sudo -i" instead of just "sudo".

Comment: @RACING121 Doesn't change anything

Comment: Try with `sudo apt-key add -`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What would be the reason for this? Do I have to add something after:
>
> ```
> apt-key add
> ```

Yes. Exactly. Look at the [official INetSim installation instructions](http://www.inetsim.org/packages.html) and look at your command in the text example here:

```
sudo wget -O - 'http://www.inetsim.org/inetsim.org-archive-signing-key.asc' | apt-key add -
```

Note the `-` at the end right after `apt-key add`. Now look at your screenshot and the command you are using; text version below:

```
sudo wget -O - 'http://www.inetsim.org/inetsim.org-archive-signing-key.asc' | apt-key add
```

You are not including that `-` after `apt-key add`. So the output from `sudo wget -O -` which should be piped to `apt-key add -`. So yes, you definitely have a broken pipe happening—or not happening—right there.

Answer (score 8):

You have to run

```
apt-key list
```

If there is an error of package `gnupg` not installed so you have to install it

```
sudo apt install gnupg && sudo apt install gnupg1
```

or

```
sudo apt install gnupg && sudo apt install gnupg2
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily add `sudo` before `apt-key`, just like this:

```
sudo wget -O - 'http://www.inetsim.org/inetsim.org-archive-signing-key.asc' | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with a docker image I was creating. I was using a slim base image which has only a minimal set of packages installed.

To investigate the issue I retrieved the key-file first. After this I tried the import command which failed. But this time I got a decent error message, which stated that I need to install gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 packages. After I installed these packages import is working succesfully.

So I'd suggest that anyone facing this issue would first retrieve the key

```
wget http://[server]/file.key
```

and then do the import with

```
apt-key add file.key
```

If this still fails atleast you'll see the cause for failure.

Comment: thanks for explaining, I had the same issue with a miniconda3 base image which uses debian 10

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I discovered that was due to missing gpg package.
I solve the problem with:

```
sudo aptitude install gpg
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to missing gnupg
Try

```
apt install gnupg
apt install gnupg1
apt install gnupg2
```

It fixes the issue

Answer (score -1):

This type of broken pipe might also result when trying to write to a directory  the current user doesn't have enough permissions.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: @Toto Thanks for the downvote Toto, I had two colleagues getting this error simply because they did not have enough permissions to the specific subdirectory that they were trying to write to. This answer, though trivial, might be the case for someone who's a newbie.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not the downvoter! Your answer doesn't add substantial info but I think it doesn't  deserve  a downvote.